# New column using ifelse() based on partial contents of string in R

Tags: r, stringr

I am trying to create a new column in my database `ref_gene_name` based on the contents of an existing column `ref_transcript_name`. Some of the entries in `ref_transcript_name` contain variant information (e.g. ",transcript variant X1"), however the variant number changes throughout the data set (i.e. X1, X2, etc.). I would like to create the new column to include everything before the transcript variant string (if a variant exists) or just print the `ref_transcript_name` in the `ref_gene_name` column. My plan here was to use an `ifelse()` statement, but I can't get it to work because of the variation in the numeral following the "X" in the variant number.

This is what I'm trying to produce:
[image]

Here is a subset of my data:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(ref_gene_id = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "LOC108906575", 
NA, "LOC108906574", "LOC108906571", "LOC108906589", "LOC108906589", 
"LOC108906588", "LOC108906588", "LOC108906588", "LOC108906588", 
"LOC108906588", "LOC108906588", "LOC108906588", "LOC108906588", 
NA, NA, "LOC108906578", "LOC108906578", "LOC108906579"), qry_gene_id = structure(c(1L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("G1", "G10", 
"G11", "G12", "G13", "G14", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5", "G6", "G7", 
"G8", "G9"), class = "factor"), ref_transcript_id = c("unknown_transcript_1", 
"unknown_transcript_1", "unknown_transcript_1", "unknown_transcript_1", 
"unknown_transcript_1", "unknown_transcript_1", "XM_018709876.1", 
NA, "XM_018709875.1", "XM_018709871.1", "XM_018709894.2", "XM_018709894.2", 
"XM_018709891.1", "XM_018709891.1", "XM_018709891.1", "XM_018709891.1", 
"XM_018709891.1", "XM_018709891.1", "XM_018709891.1", "XM_018709891.1", 
NA, NA, "XM_018709878.1", "XM_018709879.1", "XM_018709881.2"), 
    qry_transcript_id = structure(c(1L, 12L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
    23L, 24L, 25L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), .Label = c("TU1", "TU10", 
    "TU11", "TU12", "TU13", "TU14", "TU15", "TU16", "TU17", "TU18", 
    "TU19", "TU2", "TU20", "TU21", "TU22", "TU23", "TU24", "TU25", 
    "TU3", "TU4", "TU5", "TU6", "TU7", "TU8", "TU9"), class = "factor"), 
    ref_transcript_name = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    2L, NA, 2L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
    NA, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2", 
    "fork head domain transcription factor slp2-like", "peroxisomal biogenesis factor 19, transcript variant X1", 
    "peroxisomal biogenesis factor 19, transcript variant X2", 
    "ribosomal RNA processing protein 1 homolog", "uncharacterized LOC108906571", 
    "uncharacterized LOC108906589"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a regex, not `ifelse`. The following looks for:

- `,?` an optional comma
- `*` (space-asterisk) zero or more spaces (after the comma)
- `transcript variant X`, the literal text
- `[0-9]*` zero or more numbers; you can also use `[0-9]+` (plus instead of asterisk) if it *always* has at least one number-digit

and replaces all of that with the empty string `""` (i.e., deletes it from each string).

Note: regexes can be powerful and confusing. When done poorly, they can be over-greedy and change/delete way more than expected. One regex strategy is to be as specific as reasonable. In this case, `[0-9]*` (zero or more) versus `[0-9]+` (one or more) is a minor difference. As a counter-example, if the `transcript variant` text *must* be after a comma (and a sentence that begins with it should not be adjusted), then you might change the `,?` to `,`. Thoughts.

```r
zz$ref_gene_name <- sub(",? *transcript variant X[0-9]*", "",  
                        as.character(zz$ref_transcript_name))
zz[,5:6]
#                                        ref_transcript_name                                   ref_gene_name
# 1                                                     <NA>                                            <NA>
# 2                                                     <NA>                                            <NA>
# 3                                                     <NA>                                            <NA>
# 4                                                     <NA>                                            <NA>
# 5                                                     <NA>                                            <NA>
# 6                                                     <NA>                                            <NA>
# 7          fork head domain transcription factor slp2-like fork head domain transcription factor slp2-like
# 8                                                     <NA>                                            <NA>
# 9          fork head domain transcription factor slp2-like fork head domain transcription factor slp2-like
# 10                            uncharacterized LOC108906571                    uncharacterized LOC108906571
# 11                            uncharacterized LOC108906589                    uncharacterized LOC108906589
# 12                            uncharacterized LOC108906589                    uncharacterized LOC108906589
# 13       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 14       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 15       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 16       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 17       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 18       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 19       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 20       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 21                                                    <NA>                                            <NA>
# 22                                                    <NA>                                            <NA>
# 23 peroxisomal biogenesis factor 19, transcript variant X1                peroxisomal biogenesis factor 19
# 24 peroxisomal biogenesis factor 19, transcript variant X2                peroxisomal biogenesis factor 19
# 25              ribosomal RNA processing protein 1 homolog      ribosomal RNA processing protein 1 homolog
```

Answer (score 0):

Another regex pattern can solve your question in this case.

```
library(stringr)
test %>% 
  mutate(ref_gene_name = str_replace(ref_transcript_name, regex(", transcript variant X\\d{1,}"), ""))
ref_transcript_name                                   ref_gene_name
# 1                                                     <NA>                                            <NA>
# 2                                                     <NA>                                            <NA>
# 3                                                     <NA>                                            <NA>
# 4                                                     <NA>                                            <NA>
# 5                                                     <NA>                                            <NA>
# 6                                                     <NA>                                            <NA>
# 7          fork head domain transcription factor slp2-like fork head domain transcription factor slp2-like
# 8                                                     <NA>                                            <NA>
# 9          fork head domain transcription factor slp2-like fork head domain transcription factor slp2-like
# 10                            uncharacterized LOC108906571                    uncharacterized LOC108906571
# 11                            uncharacterized LOC108906589                    uncharacterized LOC108906589
# 12                            uncharacterized LOC108906589                    uncharacterized LOC108906589
# 13       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 14       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 15       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 16       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 17       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 18       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 19       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 20       ephrin type-B receptor 1-B, transcript variant X2                      ephrin type-B receptor 1-B
# 21                                                    <NA>                                            <NA>
# 22                                                    <NA>                                            <NA>
# 23 peroxisomal biogenesis factor 19, transcript variant X1                peroxisomal biogenesis factor 19
# 24 peroxisomal biogenesis factor 19, transcript variant X2                peroxisomal biogenesis factor 19
# 25              ribosomal RNA processing protein 1 homolog      ribosomal RNA processing protein 1 homolog
```